# userdata is not getting executed from terraform module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to write ec2 module, currently i am stuck with the user data.

```
resource "aws_instance" "jumphost" {
  ami                    = "${var.ami}"
  instance_type          = "${var.instancetype}"
  availability_zone      = "${var.availability_zone}"
  key_name               = "${var.key}"
  subnet_id              = join(",", var.subnet)
  associate_public_ip_address = "true"
  vpc_security_group_ids = "${var.vpc_security_group_ids}"
  iam_instance_profile   = "${var.iam_instance_profile}"
  user_data = <<EOF
  #!/bin/bash -x
  echo "======USER SCRIPT START==========="
  touch /tmp/somename
  echo "======USER SCRIPT END==========="
  EOF

tags = {
    Name = "${var.name}"
  }
}
```

I don't see the reason why this particular user_data block is not getting executed.

Comment: `> /var/log/cloud-init-output.log` is not a valid linux command. Its not clear what do you want to do.

Comment: Ok i have removed the > /var/log/cloud-init-output.log and > /var/log/cloud-init.log, but still i don't see file created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from those commands, your indentation is incorrect. It should be:

```
resource "aws_instance" "jumphost" {
  ami                    = "${var.ami}"
  instance_type          = "${var.instancetype}"
  availability_zone      = "${var.availability_zone}"
  key_name               = "${var.key}"
  subnet_id              = join(",", var.subnet)
  associate_public_ip_address = "true"
  vpc_security_group_ids = "${var.vpc_security_group_ids}"
  iam_instance_profile   = "${var.iam_instance_profile}"
  user_data = <<EOF
#!/bin/bash -x
echo "======USER SCRIPT START==========="
touch /tmp/somename
echo "======USER SCRIPT END==========="
EOF

tags = {
    Name = "${var.name}"
  }
}
```

Other than that you have to [debug userdata yourself](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) by checking `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` , as only you have access to your instance.

Comment: thank you it worked, i never thought indention would be a problem here.

Comment: @rahuls_ Yes, when you are using `<<EOF` indentation is important.